# Insert Null Value in MySQL via Powershell

Tags: mysql, powershell

I receive data from a webservice and want to insert it into a MySQL database with Powershell. Unfortunatly datetime values ($outdat) could get null.
But I do not manage to insert a null value in that case. Inserting dates works. Here is the basic code:

I have already tried with $outdat = $null, '' and [DBNull]::Value, none of them works.

```
$MySQLAdminUserName = 'xxx'
$MySQLAdminPassword = 'xxx'
$MySQLDatabase = 'xxx'
$MySQLHost = 'localhost'
$ConnectionString = "server=" + $MySQLHost + ";port=3306;uid=" + $MySQLAdminUserName + ";pwd=" + $MySQLAdminPassword + ";database="+$MySQLDatabase

    Try {
        [void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("MySql.Data")
        $Connection = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection
        $Connection.ConnectionString = $ConnectionString
        $Connection.Open()

        $MySqlCommand = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand
        $MySqlCommand.Connection = $Connection

        $inoid = "123457"
        $outdat = [DBNull]::Value
        $insid = "Hello World"


            $MySqlCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO order_all_test (order_id, shop_id, hgsp_out_date) VALUES ('$inoid', '$insid', '$outdat');"
            $MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() | Out-Null
            $lastId = $MySqlCommand.get_LastInsertedId()

        }

        Catch {
            Write-Host "ERROR : Unable to run query : $query `n$Error[0]"
        }

        Finally {
            $Connection.Close()
            }
```

Comment: `"INSERT INTO order_all_test (order_id, shop_id) VALUES ('$inoid', '$insid');"` (eliminating a column from `INSERT INTO` should leave that column uninitialized however, at the moment, I can't verify whether  it's the same as dbnull )

Comment: The problem is that I can't leave the column out completly, as sometimes I have values. How I set dbnull to outdat is just an example here for testing reasons, in reality the parameter gets filled through the webservice.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution:

```
$outdat = "NULL"
...
$MySqlCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO order_all_test (order_id, shop_id, hgsp_out_date) VALUES ('$inoid', '$insid', $outdat);"
```

So the trick was to leave out the single quotes in the sql.